# Mi librería me retorna “can't find variable” a pesae de tener todo

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una librería pequeña para **JavaScript**, y ya escribí parte de ella. El problema es que cuando edito mi librería y la pruebo en su nueva página oficial, ejecuto un comando que la llama, me dice que **no encuentra la variable donde guardé la librería**, a pesar de no haber tocado esa parte. Ya he intentado de todo y sigue sin funcionar mi librería a pesar de no tener errores sintácticos (creo).

Aquí les dejo el código:

JavaScript:

```
var textools = function() {
    
    function lowLevelEncrypt(inputText) {
        if (!inputText) {
        return;
        }
        
        var result = inputText;
        var alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","\u00D1","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
        var encryptAlphabet = ["A","B","C","D","Aa","Ab","Ac","Ad","Ba","Bb","Bc","Bd","Ca","Cb","Cc","Cd","Da","Db","Dc","Dd","Aaa","Aab","Aac","Aad","Aba","Abb","Abc"];
        var letter = 0;
        
        while (letter <= 27) {
            if (result.indexOf(alphabet[letter]) != -1) {
                result = result.replace(result.indexOf(alphabet[letter]),result.replace(result.indexOf(alphabet[letter]));
                letter++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    ;
    //Agregar función aquí
    
    return {
        lowLevelEncrypt: lowLevelEncrypt
    }
    
    
}();
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el error que estas teniendo y cómo reproducirlo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema son los paréntesis al final de la asignación, hacen que se ejecute la función y el valor de `textools` es lo que devuelve la función.

```js
var textTools1 = function() {
    return 'Valor de función 1';
}(); // Con paréntesis se ejecuta la función y se asigna el resultado

var textTools2 = function() {
    return 'Valor de función 2';
}; // Sin paréntesis, se asigna la función

// Sin ejecutar, solo saber qué contiene cada variable
console.log(textTools1); // Cadena
console.log(textTools2); // Función

// Ejecutando
console.log(textTools2()); // Cadena
console.log(textTools1()); // Error: No es una función
```

Revisando tu código original, tienes un error en esta parte; separé las líneas para poder agregar comentarios:

```
result = result.replace(
    // Primer argumento de replace parece bien
    // Aunque creo que no debería ser numérico
    result.indexOf(alphabet[letter]),
    // El segundo argumento no es correcto:
    result.replace(
        // Solo un argumento
        result.indexOf(alphabet[letter])
        // Falta cierre de paréntesis el segundo replace()
); // Cierre del primer .replace()
```

De acuerdo al manual de [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) debes proporcionar dos parámetros, aunque puedes omitir el segundo, pero devolverá `undefined`.

Aparte, creo que el segundo argumento para la primera función debería ser tomado de la variable `encryptAlphabet` para buscar obtener el resultado que deseas.

Comment: Entonces qué debería hacer?

Comment: Sin paréntesis me sigue marcando error línea 1 columna 15

Comment: @TechManWalker, revisa la respuesta actualizada. En cuanto a lo que deberías hacer, simplemente elimina los paréntesis al final de la función para que no se ejecute al asignarla.